# Class Not Declared in Scope

Tags: c++

Getting a "throttle not declared in this scope" error when I attempt to compile the main.cpp. I am very new to c++, so bear with me. I have the `#include "throttle.h"` in the headers for both cpp files, so I am not sure why when i try to create a throttle object is is not declared...

main.cpp file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "throttle.h"

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
throttle throt1(5, 0);
throttle throt2(4, 0);
return 0;
}
```

throttle.h file:

```
#ifndef MAIN_SAVITCH_THROTTLE 
#define MAIN_SAVITCH_THROTTLE     

namespace main_savitch_2A
{
class throttle
{
public:
    // CONSTRUCTORS
    //throttle( );
    //throttle(int size);
    throttle(int size = 1, int start = 0); //by adding this default 
                                           //constructor the other two 
                                           //are not needed
    // MODIFICATION MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    void shut_off( ) { position = 0; }
    void shift(int amount);
    // CONSTANT MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    double flow( ) const 
    { 
        return position / double(top_position); 
        }

    bool is_on( ) const 
    { 
        return (position > 0); 
    }

    int get_top_position()const;
    int get_position()const;

    friend bool operator <(const throttle& throt1, const throttle& throt2);
    //postcondtion: returns true if flow of throt1 < flow of throt2. 
    //return false if flow of throt1 > flow of throt2

private:
    int top_position;
    int position;
};
}
#endif
```

throttle.cpp file :

```
#include <cassert>     // Provides assert
#include "throttle.h"  // Provides the throttle class definition
using namespace std;   // Allows all Standard Library items to be used

namespace main_savitch_2A
{

//throttle::throttle( )
//{   // A simple on-off throttle
    //top_position = 1;
    //position = 0;
//}

//throttle::throttle(int size)
// Library facilities used: cassert
//{
    //assert(size > 0);
    //top_position = size;
    //position = 0;
//}

throttle::throttle(int size, int start)
{
    assert(size > 0);
    assert(start = 0);
    top_position = size;
    position = start;
}

void throttle::shift(int amount)
{
position += amount;

if (position < 0)
    position = 0;
else if (position > top_position)
    position = top_position;
}

bool operator <(const throttle& throt1, const throttle& throt2)
{
    return(throt1.flow() < throt2.flow());
}

int throttle::get_top_position()const
{
    return top_position;
}

int throttle::get_position()const
{
    return position;

}
}
```

Comment: Or a `using namespace main_savitch_2A;` in you main.cpp.

Comment: Ohhh I see because this is the namespace specified in the .h file and the cpp. thank you!

Comment: An unrelated question: How do I cal the bool operator established in the .h file in the main.cpp file? Or is it supposed to execute during the throttle.cpp file? Because as of right now it is not

Comment: The less-than operator executes only if you call it.  E.g. `auto isLess = throt1 < throt1;` in your main.cpp.

Answer (score 3):

In your main, it should be `main_savitch_2A::throttle throt1(5, 0);`.
The same for `throt2`.

See [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) for further details.

Comment: An unrelated question: How do I cal the bool operator established in the .h file in the main.cpp file? Or is it supposed to execute during the throttle.cpp file? Because as of right now it is not.